# Google Event Create API - img tag not loading

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google Calendar API to create Calendar Event.

In the Description for the event, I'm passing complete HTML containing Anchor tag, Image tags. Anchor tags are loading fine but images in the image tag is not loading.
When I inspect the Created Calendar event, I see the given image tag URL is wrapped by google URL. If I load the URL in another tab, it is redirecting to the actual URL.

I have tried styles with back-ground image passing URL, still it is not working.

Below is the HTML Description I'm using:

```html
<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset='utf-8'></head><body style='padding:' 0px;='' margin:='' 0px;'='' style='background: #eeeeee; background-color: #eeeeee;'><div>This is main Div</div><div><a href='https://www.google.com/'>Google website </a></div><div><img src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfuM1.png' alt="test"></div></body></html>
```

Please refer to all the images.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w0U5.png)
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfuM1.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]  i would love to try.  Where in the documentation does it state the description supports html tags?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Calendar API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert) HTML tags are optional, so it should be supported. However, in terms of HTML Image tags, they may not be supported as images in events are created as attachments. That could be the reason why the image does not show in the Calendar event result.

Moreover, you can use these values below for attaching images.

"attachments": [
{
"fileUrl": "URL link"
}
]

Comment: Did you patch the calendar with supportsAttachments: Whether API client performing operation supports event attachments. Optional. The default is False.
https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch